# Integrating IntelliJ with Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have set `M2_HOME` variable to the required directory in `.bash_profile`, still I am getting the following error:

> Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.[ERROR] Maven execution terminated abnormally (exit code 1)

Answer (score 0):

One solution (but it's only a workaround) may be to set console argument

> "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory="

Then the project should work. 
I have the same problem while building maven projects from eclipse with system maven installation.

Comment: It was not working even after setting the flag, I upgraded intellij, it was a known bug in intellij

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137783

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured maven in IntelliJ?

[image]

Comment: I upgraded intellij, it was a known bug in intellij

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137783

Comment: @Saurabh Araiyer, good to know that, you have fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can change your maven's version to 3.1.1.

I met the problem too: My version of maven was 3.3.3, and then I changed it to 3.1.1 and it worked.

Comment: Downgrading also didn't helped in my case, later I found out that its a known bug

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137783